# Flutter: Parse data through pages in BottomNavigationBar. Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: parsing, flutter, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have a BottomNavigationbar and I want to parse data through the parameters! I get the error: Only static members  can be accessed in initializers.

```
class _LoggedInStudentState extends State<LoggedInStudent> {

final String bearer;
final String username;
_LoggedInStudentState(this.bearer, this.username);

int _selectedPage = 0;

List<Widget> _pageOptions = [
  StudentHomePage(bearer, username),
  StudentProjectPage(),
  StudentStudyplanPage()
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  endDrawer: Drawer(),
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black54),
    elevation: 0,
  ),
  body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    currentIndex: _selectedPage,
    onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedPage = index;
      });
    },
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Hem')
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text("Skolprojekt")
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
          title: Text("Studieplaner")
        ),
      ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

More info about how the homepage is set up: As you. can se I define the final String bearer and final String username.

```
class _StudentHomePageState extends State<StudentHomePage> {

final String bearer;
final String username;
_StudentHomePageState(this.bearer, this.username);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[

      Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(child: Text('Välkommen Tillbaka', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),), alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),
              Container(child: Text('${username.toUpperCase()[0]}${username.substring(1)}!', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),), alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),

            ],
          )
      )

    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Is this a problem because the pages are in an array? This always works when I do navigator.push to a page. If someone has the soulution. Feel free to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are trying to build _pageOptions, bearer and username are not defined since they are passed when the object is constructed. If those variables were "constants" you can just declare as static it will work.

Since in this case you need to build page options with dynamic data you need to setup your pageOptions after you build the _LoggedInStudentState, because at this point you already have bearer and username.

Try something like this:

```
class _LoggedInStudentState extends State<LoggedInStudent> {

final String bearer;
final String username;
final List<Widget> _pageOptions;
_LoggedInStudentState(this.bearer, this.username)
  : _pageOptions = [
      StudentHomePage(bearer, username),
      StudentProjectPage(),
      StudentStudyplanPage()
    ];

int _selectedPage = 0;
```

Comment: The request goes through now, is authenticated and everything but I can't pull any data through it?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what request you are talking about, the original question was about the initialization of the widget and the error "Only static members can be accessed in initializers". If problem was solved maybe you should mark this as solved and make a new question to provide the details about this new problem.